# Flex-Direction: Column; not working in a @media style rule

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Bear with me here since I'm still learning how to code fully. I'm trying to write a code that, on desktop, will display a navigational bar on the right side of the screen. When displayed on something smaller than 800px, however, I want it displayed as a column instead of a row. Whenever I try setting this up though, it only displays in a row and won't turn to a column form below 800px.
Any and all help is appreciated!

```css
body {
    background: #135e46;
}

div {
    background: #73a788;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1em;
    flex-direction: row;
}

a {
    color: #e9d0bd;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 10px;
}

@media(max-width:800px){

body {
    background: #135e46;

}

div {
    background: #73a788;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 1em;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: -10px;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
}

a {
    color: #e9d0bd;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
        Title
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="items/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <nav>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
            <a href="#">Education</a>
            <a href="#">Resume</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `display:flex` and `flex-direction:column` to your `nav` element to display `a` elements in column.

So if your `div` have only one child it's normal to see any changes except if you look at the main axis ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction )

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

So you can remove all flexbox's properties in div's media query and set navbar location using `justify-content` ( for the horizontal axis ) or `align-items` ( for vertical axis ). Make sure you have a large enough container if you want to move your navbar on the vertical axis.

If you have properties defined outside of your media queries you don't need to rewrite them. Media queries are just a sort overwriting system which depend on media. ( screen size usually )

```css
body {
    background: #135e46;
}

div {
    background: #73a788;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1em;
    flex-direction: row;
}

a {
    color: #e9d0bd;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 10px;
}

@media(max-width:800px){

body {
    background: #135e46;

}

div {
    justify-content:center;
    margin-top: -10px;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

nav{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}


}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
        Title
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="items/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <nav>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
            <a href="#">Education</a>
            <a href="#">Resume</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to turn `a` tag to `block` from default `inline`

```css
body {
    background: #135e46;
}

div {
    background: #73a788;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1em;
    flex-direction: row;
}

a {
    color: #e9d0bd;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 10px;
}

@media(max-width:800px){

body {
    background: #135e46;

}

div {
    background: #73a788;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 1em;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: -10px;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
}

a {
    color: #e9d0bd;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    display:block /* added this rule */
}
  

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
        Title
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="items/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <nav>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
            <a href="#">Education</a>
            <a href="#">Resume</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `a` tags are `inline` elements by default, not `inline-block`

Comment: I appreciate it, this seems to have fixed to exactly what I needed! I knew it would be an easy fix, but I had such a brain stump trying to figure out why it wouldn't flex the same way as I had done it before